# group has_many members as array of member_ids in postgres db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a members table, and groups table.

The members table just has an id and a name attribute.

The groups table has an id, name, and members_ids as an array

```
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :member_ids, array: true, default: []

      t.date :created_at, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

the member_ids are represented like this in the db:

{12,45,23,67,78}

I'm trying to understand how to properly the relationships. Is it possible to create a relationship with the member_ids the way they are so that I can eager load the groups and members for display? Or will have to do a find on each array of ids?

Comment: How u defined associations between group and members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrays to store ids might seem clever but arrays are ordered sets - not relational data structures.

It does not work with ActiveRecord assocations and there are very few if any databases that currently support foreign key arrays. See: [The Importance of the Foreign Key Constraint](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/importance-foreign-key-constraint-tim-miles).

Making a many to many association between users and groups is done by using a join table. Generate it with:

```
rails g model membership user:belongs_to group:belongs_to
```

Then lets setup our assocations:

```
class User< ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :user, through: :memberships
end
```

This lets us go straight from user to groups and vice versa and rails will handle joining and creating the join rows.

For example:

```
@group.members << current_user # makes the current_user a member
@user.groups.pluck(:name)  # returns an array of the names of the users groups.
```

To eager load the records you would do:

```
Group.eager_load(:members)
# or 
User.eager_load(:groups)
```